# How to import local modules in a PyPI project?

Tags: python, pypi

I have a PyPI project and I want to import local modules in it (Modules that I have made specifically for this project). My directory structure looks like this :

```
├── __init__.py

├── albumsearch.py

├── command_line.py

├── improvename.py
```

Inside command_line.py , I have :

```
''' local modules'''
import albumsearch
import improvename
```

When I register with PyPI, I get an error saying that these modules do not exist.

How can I access local modules on a PyPI project without registering them on PyPI seperately?

Setup.py looks like this :

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='package_name',
      version='',
      description='',
      url='',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      license='',
      packages =['package_name'],
      install_requires=[
          'bs4',
      ],
      entry_points = {
          'console_scripts': ['package_name=package_name.command_line:main'],
      },
      )
```

Comment: Isn't it nescessary to use py_modules to list all modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package already a python package because you have `__init__.py` so with `.` you can access modules in same package

```
#command_line
from . import albumsearch
from . import improvename
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect! Can't believe I stumbled upon something like this.

Comment: you are welcome but I recomend you check python import

Comment: What is the difference between using a local import (like your suggestion) and a global one, like ` from module_name.local_file import albumsearch` ?) Is there a recommended way ?